# setInterval and long running functions

Tags: javascript, setinterval

How does setInterval handle callback functions that take longer than the desired interval?

I've read that the callback may receive the number of milliseconds late as its first argument, but I was unable to find why it would be late (jitter, or long running functions).

And the wonderful follow up, does it behave differently for the common browsers?

Comment: Good question. I would suspect the answer is browser specific. Should we run some tests to find out?

Comment: I wouldn't rely on receiving any arguments to the callback. Instead, use a simple Date comparison. That seems the most reliable and cross-browser approach to me.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Let me quote an excellent [article](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/) about timers by John Resig:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  /* Some long block of code... */
  setTimeout(arguments.callee, 10);
}, 10);

setInterval(function(){
  /* Some long block of code... */
}, 10);
```

> These two pieces of code may appear to
> be functionally equivalent, at first
> glance, but they are not. Notably the
> setTimeout code will always have at
> least a 10ms delay after the previous
> callback execution (it may end up
> being more, but never less) whereas
> the setInterval will attempt to
> execute a callback every 10ms
> regardless of when the last callback
> was executed.
>
> Intervals may execute back-to-back with no delay if they take long enough to execute (longer than the specified delay).

Comment: So, in a nutshell, because JavaScript threading is all single threaded, the callbacks cannot be running in parallel. Perfect.