# SetTimeout recursive with arrow function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I would like to know if there is a way to use setTimeout recursive implements with an arrow function, in order to use `this` (refers to my class attribute for example) inside. Indeed, `this = undefined` when i declare my setTimeout with a normal function

I got :

```
public currentIndex: number = 0;

setTimeout(function run(){
    this.currentIndex++;
    console.log(this.currentIndex); // returns undefined
    setTimeout(run, 1000);
}, 1000)
```

Instead of :

```
setTimeout(() => {
    this.currentIndex++;
    console.log(this.currentIndex) // returns currentIndex value
    setTimeout( ?? , 1000) // What should i put instead of '??' ?
}, 1000)
```

Comment: Are you looking for `setInterval` instead to do your recursive job? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval

Comment: As I answered to ciekals11, `setInterval` seems to not be adapted in my case, due to executing time of my code inside

Comment: Another approach could be a loop that pauses between iterations using `await` like `for(;;await delay(1000)){ this.currentIndex++; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could bind `this` first and then use this function for all calls.

```
function run(reference) {
    this.currentIndex++;
    console.log(this.currentIndex); // returns undefined
    setTimeout(reference, 1000, reference);
}

const runThis = run.bind(thisReference);

setTimeout(runThis, 1000, runThis);
```

Answer (score 1):

Its because arrow function does not create new context inside arrow function body but normal function does. So this in arrow function refers to parent scope context but this in normal function refers to its own context.

Answer (score 1):

This will create setTimeouts recursively

```js
let currentIndex = 0;

const run = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        currentIndex++;
        console.log(currentIndex);
        run();
    }, 1000);
}

run();
```

but better approach may be (I don't know your use case, so it is just maybe) to use [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval)

```js
let currentIndex = 0;

const interval = setInterval(() => {
    currentIndex++;
    console.log(currentIndex);

    // stop interval
    if (currentIndex >= 10) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: I would have used `setInterval` but I saw that the interval chosen is not guarantee, due to execution time of the program. For example, if the code inside take longer than expected, the time will be impacted. Is that true ?

Comment: I think that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1976535/9074272) answers your question

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way is to extract the arrow function into its own variable:

```js
const run = () => {
    this.currentIndex++;
    console.log(this.currentIndex);
    setTimeout(run, 1000);
};
setTimeout(run, 1000);
```

Though in this particular example you could simplify it even more using `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`, avoiding the second `setTimeout` call entirely.